# Different background and collectionCell separator color in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have to create a UI which has 3 `UICollectionViewCell` in a row. So i created it using `UICollectionViewController`, with section = 1 and no of rows = coming from api. So i was able to create 6 cells in which every row contains 3 cells. These cells are separated by 0.5 pt vertically and horizontally.
I have given the background color to collectionView which comes in separator.

In particular this is what i need :-
[image: CollectionViewCntroller]

Problem :-
This is the type of `UICollectionViewController` requirement i have 
The separators needs to be red, and the space not rendered needs to be yellow. But I am unable to do that, I can have a single background color for `UICollectionView` which shows for both separator and free space. Is there a way to have different colors.

I dont want to use UITableView and have a UICollectionView inside `UITableViewCell`. I know this approach but i want to do the same in `UICollectionViewController`.

Comment: I didnt understand what do you want. are you saying that you need the hoo-space to be red and the ver-space to be yellow?

Comment: No, horizontal and vertical separators should be of same color. But the space left after rendering all cells should be of different color

Comment: @hasan83 I have edited the question. Let me know if it is still nor clear

Comment: there is only one problem I guess in both the answers. mine and sti. I am not sure that the view frame can act properly with the value after the floating point at least not for all devices. the other solution is to draw those line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you can solve this by removing the space between the cells. Remove the 0.5pt space entirely. Then, all cells will be glued to each other, and you can create your own separators *inside* each cell. It'll require some logic though, because all cells should not use the same separators (if you do, then the center cells will have double separators on each side).

To achieve your photo, you could set these rules:

The **first** and the **last** cell in each row should only show a separator on bottom. 
All the other cells in between (in your case, one cell in between) should show separator on bottom, left, **and** right.

To add these separators, just go into your custom `UICollectionViewCell` and add some `UIViews` to each side, and set them to have a width of 0.5pt, and set them visible on demand.

Comment: thanks that did my work . i though may be there is some great way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a custom cell as Sti suggested. I usually do that. but an easier way would be:

> To add a subview to the collectionView every time you reload data of
>   the collection view.

**Code:**

```
let count: CGFloat = CGFloat(items.count)
let numberOfRows: CGFloat = ceil(count / 3.0)
let height: CGFloat = numberOfRows * (cellHeight + seperatorHeight)
if collectionBackView != nil { // controller member object
    collectionBackView.removeFromSuperview()
}

collectionBackView = UIView(frame: 
    CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: height))
collectionView.addSubview(collectionBackView)
collectionView.sendSubview(toBack: collectionBackView)
```